# A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink VARCHAR ' to length 1000

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, derby

I know there is similar issues already.

In this case, the string

`BM01-20170821-139, BM01-20170727-04, BM01-20170727-05, BM01-&`

is clearly less than 1000 characters long.

This is the error message:

`javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.1.v20171221-bd47e8f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLDataException: A truncation error was encountered trying to shrink VARCHAR 'BM01-20170821-139, BM01-20170727-04, BM01-20170727-05, BM01-&' to length 1000.
Error Code: 20000`

I assume it prints the string that is too long. Maybe the error message contains only a substring?

Comment: What is the error exactly and what are you doing - we can't help without more information, such as why you think it is this string causing the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question.

Comment: This is an exception coming from your DB, it might be referring to bytes not characters, and while it seems unlikely this string wouldn't fit it entirely depends on the character sets involved.  How did you define the table, and does it work for other strings?

Comment: Using google to look up the error suggest that the DB is truncating the string in the error message. This is only the first part of the string that is causing the issue using '&' to denote it was truncated. Your string may well be >1000 characters.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks a lot! I will debug this further.. You can post this as an answer if you like.